# Water Powered Cars - What are these things?

Tags: fuel-system, car

Whilst looking up the answer to [another question using Google](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=do+cars+release+much+water%3F) regarding the water output from a normal internal combusted engine powered car, I noticed that - to my surprise - all the top hits were about **water powered cars**. Cars that run on water are actually a thing apparently!

- ***What are water powered cars?***
- ***How exactly do they work?***

Comment: Water powered cars!  What are these things?    :-)    +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer - they are a hoax, and they don't work.

The only way to power a car with water is to electrolyse the water into Hydrogen and Oxygen using an external power source (and it uses a lot of energy to do this), store the Hydrogen in the car and use that (with oxygen from the atmosphere) to power a Hydrogen fuel cell - the output from which is water and energy. Like every other system, there are losses involved, so you always get less energy out than you put in - that's a fundamental law of physics...